# Unitary operators that implement the same canonical transformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, representation-theory, commutator, unitarity

In quantum mechanics a transformation of the spatial coordinate operators and conjugate momentums of the type: $$(q_1,\dots,q_n,p_1,\dots,p_n) \to (Q_1,\dots,Q_n,P_1,\dots,P_n),$$ is called canonical transformation if the commutators are conserved, i.e. if $$[q_i,p_j]=iħ\delta_{ij}=[Q_i,P_j]$$ for each $i,j=1,\dots,n$. It can be demonstrated (von Neumann's theorem, see for example the Picasso lectures in quantum mechanics, chapter 6, page 108,) that a unitary operator $U$ can be associated to each canonical transformation of this type such that $$Q_i=Uq_iU^{\dagger}$$ and $$P_i =Up_iU^{\dagger}$$ for each $i=1,...,n$ (here $U^{\dagger}$ represents the adjoint of $U$). My question is: how is it possible to prove that if $U$ and $V$ are two unitary operators associated with the same canonical transformation, then they differ only by a phase factor? i.e. $U=e^{i\phi}V$, where $\phi$ is a real number.

Comment: You can derive it from Schur’s lemma. The key assumption, is that your Hilbert space is an irreducible representation of the canonical commutation relations (Weyl form). You were having a hard time because you weren’t exploiting irreducibility. So any braiding automorphism is a multiple of identity.

Comment: You are perfectly right, but I was hoping for something more direct and physical. I would like to avoid Schur's lemma and the concept of irreducible representation. I think I succeeded in this task, in a moment I will post my proof.

Comment: If you believe that your attempt solves the problem, you should post it as a (self) answer instead of adding it to the question.

Comment: Oh, okay, sorry. I'm going to do it right now.

Comment: Doesn't any proof *imply* irreducibility?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch irreducibility is a great tool for a proof of this. However, I was looking for a more direct approach (even less rigorous, but more physical). I would like to avoid the concept of irreducibility and Schur's lemma, which are tools that are not familiar to the vast majority of students who encounter for the first time quantum mechanics.

Comment: @Leonardo What I am saying is: Whatever your proof does, a consequence of it will be that the Hilbert space is irreducible (otherwise, there *would* be other $U$s). So proving it must be at least as hard as proving irreducibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own attempt (I noticed that I made a mistake in my previous attempt, so I fixed my proof)

Let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be the unitary operators implementing the same canonical transformation

$(q_1,\dots,q_n,p_1,\dots,p_n) \to (Q_1,\dots,Q_n,P_1,\dots,P_n)$

We define the operator $V=U_2^{\dagger}U_1$. Clearly $V$ is unitary. Furthermore $Vq_iV^{\dagger}=q_i$ and $Vp_iV^{\dagger}=p_i$ for each $i=1,\dots,n$. So in particular for every polynomial function $f(q,p)$ we have that $Vf(q,p)V^{\dagger}=f(q,p)$, that is $[V,f(q,p)]=0$. Now we define $H_i=\frac{p_i^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2q_i^2$, i.e. the Hamiltonian of the one-dimensional harmonic oscillator associated to the pair $(q_i,p_i)$. As known, this non-degenerate self-adjoint operator gives a Hilbert basis of eigenvectors $|k_i\rangle$ with $k_i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $H_i|k_i\rangle=E_i|k_i\rangle$ where $E_i=\hbar\omega(k_i+\frac{1}{2})$. However, we are working in a Hilbert space with n degrees of freedom, so its basis will rather be given by $|k_1,\dots,k_n\rangle$, where $H_i|k_1,\dots,k_n\rangle=E_i|k_1,\dots,k_n\rangle$ for each $i=1,\dots,n$, i.e. $|k_1,\dots,k_n\rangle$ are simultaneous eigenvectors of $H_1,\dots,H_n$ (here $k_1,\dots,k_n \in \mathbb{N}^n$).

Clearly $V$ commutes with all $H_i$ and therefore $V|k_1,\dots,k_n\rangle$ is an eigenvector of each $H_i$, i.e.

$H_iV|k_1,\dots,k_n\rangle=VH_i|k_1,\dots,k_n\rangle=E_iV|k_1,\dots,k_n\rangle$ for each $i=1,\dots,n$

and, being $H_1,\dots,H_n$ a complete system of compatible observables (i.e. each $|k_1,\dots,k_n\rangle$ is univocally identified by a $n$-tuple $(k_1,\dots,k_n)$), we can say that

$V|k_1,\dots,k_n\rangle=c(k_1,\dots,k_n)|k_1,\dots,k_n\rangle$,

with $c(k_1,\dots,k_n)$ a complex number which, however, generally depends on the $n$-tuple $(k_1,\dots,k_n) \in \mathbb{N}^n$. Moreover clearly $V$ also commutes with all the $q_i$, therefore in particular, since these all together form a complete system of compatible observables too, we have that

$V|x_1,\dots,x_n\rangle=K(x_1,\dots,x_n)|x_1,\dots,x_n\rangle$,

where $|x_1,\dots,x_n\rangle$ are simultaneous eigenvector of $q_1,\dots,q_n$, i.e.

$q_i|x_1,\dots,x_n\rangle=x_i|x_1,\dots,x_n\rangle$

for each $i=1,\dots,n$. Here $K(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is a complex number depending in general on the $n$-tuple $x_1,\dots,x_n$. Now it suffices to observe that, since $|x_1,\dots,x_n\rangle$ is a (generalized) Hilbert basis as $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ varies in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then:

$|k_1',\dots,k_n'\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \langle X_1,\dots,x_n \mid k_1',\dots,k_n'\rangle |x_1,\dots,x_n\rangle \text{d}x_1\dots\text{d}x_n$,

where $|k_1,\dots,k_n\rangle$ is fixed. Applying $V$ to both sides we obtain:

$c(k_1',\dots,k_n')|k_1',\dots,k_n'\rangle=$

$=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \langle x_1,\dots,x_n \mid k_1',\dots,k_n'\rangle K(x_1,\dots,x_n)|x_1,\dots,x_n\rangle \text{d}x_1\dots\text{d}x_n$.

Multiplying on the left by an arbitrary fixed $|x_1',\dots,x_n'\rangle$ we finally obtain:

$c(k_1',\dots,k_n') \langle x_1',\dots,x_n' \mid k_1',\dots,k_n'\rangle=K(x_1',\dots,x_n') \langle x_1',\dots,x_n' \mid k_1,\dots,k_n\rangle$,

from which $c(k_1',\dots,k_n')=K(x_1',\dots,x_n')$, i.e. $K$ does not depend on the $n$-tuple $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ chosen. So $V$ is a multiple of the identity, given that, taking the generic vector:

$|A\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \langle x_1,\dots,x_n \mid A \rangle |x_1,\dots,x_n \rangle \text{d}x_1\dots\text{d}x_n$,

we have that:

$V|A\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \langle x_1,\dots,x_n \mid A \rangle V|x_1,\dots,x_n\rangle \text{d}x_1\dots\text{d}x_n=$

$=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \langle x_1,\dots,x_n \mid A \rangle K|x_1,\dots,x_n\rangle \text{d}x_1\dots\text{d}x_n=K|A\rangle$.

Since $V=KI$ (I is the identity) is unitary, we must have that $K=e^{i\phi}$. So $U_1=e^{i\phi}U_2$. What do you think? Is there any simpler approach?

Comment: Let us suppose $n=1$. Your proof assumes that there is a basis of the Hilbert space $|n>$ made of the eigenvectors of $p^2+q^2$ where $n$ is the eigenvalue. It is OK on $L^2(R)$. But now consider $H=L^2\otimes C^2$ and define $q':= q\otimes I$, $p':=p\otimes I$. Even if the new operators satisfy the CCR your proof does not work any longer.

Comment: That is because it is false that every eigenvalue of $p'^2+q'^2$ has a **unique** normalized  eigenvector up to phases.

Comment: Without irreducibility pointed out by @Norbert Schuch, or an equivalent requirement, your claim is false.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your point. Are you saying that my proof fails because the operator $p'^2+q'^2$ is degenerate?

Comment: Yes I am saying exactly that. You should assume that it is not degenerate. Your proof is a basic form if the proof of the Stone von Neumann theorem, which asserts your statement.

Comment: Okay, clear. In fact I don't assume that $q'^2+p'^2$ is non degenerate. I use a totally different thing. I use the fact that $q_i'^2+p_i'^2$, where i goes from 0 to n, is a COMPLETE system of operators (the single operators are degenerate, I agree on that).

Comment: That is equivalent to irreducibility.

Comment: Okay, so my proof with that assumption is in fact correct. Now I see your point.

Comment: As a matter of fact CCRs are not enough. You must assume another further  hypothesis, completeness of the set of observables or irreducibility of the represntation.

Comment: The theorem is the celebrated Stone von Neumann one...

Comment: Thank you, now it is clear. Yes, I implicitly assumed the completeness. Is my proof correct about the rest?

Comment: It is "correct" in the non-rigorous approach by physicists. Strictly speaking it contains a  number of issues. Regarding domains, selfadjointness problems etc. But, yes, all those issues can be fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much sir! That's all I needed to know. Yes, I know it is not rigorous, but I need only its correctness right now.

Comment: Prego..........I think there is a similar proof in the old, but beautiful book, by Caldirola Cirelli Prosperi: introduzione alla fisica teorica.

Comment: Grazie mille, very appreciated